Difference between bounded and unbounded mu operator?
From what I understand, the bounded μ-operator is a primitive recursive function (prf), while the unbounded μ-operator is not primitive recursive. What I don't understand is how this applies in practice.
Kleene's example of the bounded μ-operator from wiki is very informative. It explains the characteristic function $\chi(y)$. It explains that $\pi(y)$ and $\sigma(y)$ are defined inductively (they are prf).
Similarly, this answer gives an example of μ-operator. It's not stated, but I believe this example is unbounded.
What's the difference between these two examples? If I said "$i$ must be less than $100$" in the second example, would that turn it into a bounded μ-operator? In the first example, Kleene only gives a few values of $\chi(y)$, is that what makes it the bounded μ-operator?
Or (from the wiki page) is the difference in the definition of $\pi(y)$, which the second example doesn't even mention?

If you've done a bit of programming, a very good intuition is that the bounded one is a for loop whereas the unbounded one is a while loop.

Yes, the difference is just whether there is a given upper bound. Let $P(x)$ be a predicate on natural numbers:

with the unbounded $\mu$ operator, $(\mu x, P(x))$ is the smallest $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true.
with the bounded $\mu$ operator, $(\mu x_{x < z}, P(x))$ is the smallest $x$ less than $z$ such that $P(x)$ is true.

The point is that the unbounded $\mu$ lets you define all the computable functions, but it does searches in infinite sets, resulting in algorithms which may not terminate. The bounded $\mu$ has less expressive power, belonging to the primitive recursive functions, but the "upside" is that the algorithms behind primitive recursive functions always terminate.
